# Is it possible that all sects of Hinduism could be right about their Parabrahman?

Tags: scripture, vedas, history, kalpa

Different sects of Hinduism declare different God's as Parabrahman. Is it possible that all are true if Parabrahman takes different forms in each Kalpa?
Since Parabrahman can take any form, is the same form (eg. Shiva according to Shaivism) taken repeatedly during all Kalpas or is possible that the form is changed?

Comment: If Rudra is in Trimurti then they say Shiva is Parbrahmn but if they say Shiva is in Trimurti then Sada Shiva is Parbrahmn. Similarly, Vishnu is in Trimurti and Adi Narayan is Parbrahmn. And similarly, there is Shakti conterpart to Trimurti and Adi Shakti is Parbrahmn. So ultimately there is someone above Trimurti and Shakti.. Now they call it Adi Shakti, Sada Shiva, Adi Narayan, Maha Kala or Parbrahmn; they are ultimately talking about same: the ultimate reality..

Comment: No that is not possible. That is the same as saying that all religions are true.

Comment: TDS's comment is the answer. Parabrahman is the totality of all things, so all things are versions of it. No matter what you call the highest divinity, the totality of all things (highest divinity and that which is not the highest divinity) is larger in scope than the highest divinity. That said, this isn't the kind of question we can answer on this SE. We cannot give an answer without quoting a text and different texts were meant for (are used by) different groups, thus different names for the highest divinity. Different names emphasize different aspects so we can more easily understand.

Comment: The only pramāṇa allowed here is śabda. Specifically śruti.